# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<X>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

Shouldn't we be able to assign a value to a field **IF IT IS THE SAME TYPE UNDER THE HOOD - E.G. IN THE DEBUGGER IT SAYS IT IS A `List<GroceryItmTag>?` and you are trying to assign it to a `List<GroceryItmTag>?`**, and just cast it to the correct type or to `dynamic`? Here I am hovering over `formFieldValue`, which I later assign to `groceryItm.tags`:

[image]

`groceryItem.tags` is `List<GroceryItmTag>?` and I'm assigning to it, a field which is a `List<GroceryItmTag>?`, under the hood, even though it is not recognised as that. But it is throwing this exception whether I cast it as `List<GroceryItmTag>?` or I just cast it to `dynamic` and assign it.

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<GroceryItmTag>?'
```

How can I assign it without throwing the exception?

This is hovering over `groceryItm.tags`, the field that I am trying to assign `formFieldValue` to `{List<GroceryItmTag>? tags}`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to filter on the type and assign that. Example:

```
List<dynamic> list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

List<String> stringList = list as List<String>; //this will give a runtime error

List<String> stringList = list.whereType<String>().toList(); //workaround
```

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't we be able to assign a value to a field if it is the same type under the hood, and just cast it to the correct type or to dynamic?

## No

Simple example. If I have a `List<Sheep>` and I assign it to a `List<dynamic>`, now you could suddenly insert a `Wolf()` into my `List<Sheep>` through that `List<dynamic>` variable. Because a `Wolf` is a `dynamic`, too and you can insert into a `List<dynamic>`. That is why it does not work and will not work.

You could assign your `List<Sheep>` to a plain `dynamic` though and cast it as neccessary.

Comment: Nice explanation answer +1

Comment: Thanks. So even if they are the exact same type, as you can see in the image, I have a `List<GroceryItmTag>` and I am trying to assign it to a `List<GroceryItmTag>`, it cannot be done?

Comment: You don't. Your compiler is telling you that very clearly. You have a `List<GroceryItmTag>?` and you are trying to assign that to a `List<dynamic>` . That is not possible because of the nullability and because of that fact that even a non-null `List<X>` **is not** a `List<dynamic>` as I explained above.

Comment: I'm trying to assign it to a `List<GroceryItmTag>?`, I have added another picture (bottom) hovering over it to show the type. Is the top image actually not showing it is a `List<GroceryItmTag>` even if it says `GroceryItmTag` next to each index?

Comment: Well, what is `formFieldValue`? Maybe that is not actually a `List<GroveryItmTag>`?

Comment: My error was in my `vgnItem` not having strongly typed `tags`, but each of its implementations do, and I thought `maybeMap` turned it into whatever type was returned from the route that executed. However it was still the super type, `VeganItm` I have applied @Ivos answer but upvoted yours. Cheers